# Specifying criteria for client certificate authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, azure-web-app-service, client-certificates, kestrel

I need to setup client certificate authentication for a web app. I have a POC that works fine, except one thing: I can't figure out how to specify criteria for the client certificate (so that the browser only shows matching certificates when it prompts the user to pick one).

I know it's possible, because I've seen sites that did it, and the TLS RFC mention that the [CertificateRequest](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.3.2) can contain extensions "describing the parameters of the certificate being requested".

However, I can't find a way to do this with ASP.NET Core. I need to support this on IIS (for hosting in Azure App Service) and, if possible, on Kestrel (for local development).

Is it even possible?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm not asking how to validate the certificate once I received it. I'm asking how to specify which certificate I want (e.g. which CA issued it, etc.) during the TLS handshake.

Comment: My answer just now is that I want you to select the certificate you want in the custom method, and return true if there is one.

Comment: @JasonPan I don't understand your comment. I want to be able to specify that the user must pick (for instance) a certificate issued by a given certificate authority, at the TLS level. I know the protocol supports it. I'm asking how to do it in ASP.NET Core.